# groupby() cumsum() with 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is the correct syntax for this code:

```
db_deals['nem_col'] = db_deals.groupby(['client_id', 'acc_number'])[['swap','profit']].cumsum()
```

I want to sum the cumulative values of `swap` and `profit` columns, for unique `client_id` and `acc_number` columns.

The error message is:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Comment: That line wouldn't yield that error. Does it happen to follow something like: `db_deals['some_col'] = db_deals.groupby(...)`?

Comment: thats exactly the case. Im putting this cumsum in a column. what is the correct way?

Comment: You have two cumsum columns. They should be **two** new columns, not one. So something like `db_deals[['cumsum1','cumsum2']] = db_deals.groupby()...`?

Comment: I want to sum spread and profit in just a new single column

Comment: Chain that cumsum with .sum(1)

Comment: great. could you please tell me how the original code would be?. I tried chaining wrongly: `db_deals['new_col'] = db_deals.groupby(['client_id', 'acc_number'])['swap'].cumsum()['profit'].cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `agg()` and state which functions you want to apply to which columns.
2. `sum(axis=1)` to sum columns output from step #1
3. `sort_values()` to demonstrate it's correct

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"client_id":np.random.randint(1,3, 15),
             "acc_number":np.random.randint(150,155, 15),
                           "swap":np.random.randint(2,8, 15),
                           "profit":np.random.randint(50,75, 15),
             })

df = (df.assign(nem_col=
           df.groupby(["client_id","acc_number"]).agg({c:"cumsum" for c in ["swap","profit"]}).sum(axis=1))
 .sort_values(["client_id","acc_number"])
)
```

|  | client_id | acc_number | swap | profit | nem_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 150 | 6 | 56 | 62 |
| 4 | 1 | 150 | 3 | 54 | 119 |
| 7 | 1 | 150 | 5 | 68 | 192 |
| 1 | 1 | 152 | 6 | 67 | 73 |
| 5 | 1 | 152 | 2 | 70 | 145 |
| 13 | 1 | 152 | 2 | 66 | 213 |
| 14 | 1 | 152 | 4 | 68 | 285 |
| 2 | 1 | 153 | 3 | 67 | 70 |
| 8 | 1 | 153 | 7 | 62 | 139 |
| 12 | 1 | 153 | 2 | 74 | 215 |
| 6 | 2 | 150 | 7 | 70 | 77 |
| 3 | 2 | 152 | 2 | 50 | 52 |
| 10 | 2 | 153 | 6 | 53 | 59 |
| 11 | 2 | 153 | 2 | 63 | 124 |
| 9 | 2 | 154 | 5 | 52 | 57 |